# Does it make sense to use the subjunctive mood for a situation when things aren't real at that moment but are real a few seconds later?

Tags: grammar

At about 6:30 into the [video](https://youtu.be/vmyXZaMXuLg?t=390), the guy says: "this is something that would probably make more sense if you saw a photo." He is using the subjunctive mood as we're not looking at a photo at that moment

[image: we're not looking at a photo]

though a few seconds later we are

[image]

is my understanding correct?

In other words, when he says "if you saw a photo" he is not looking at a photo. He is making a hypothesis of the present. So, is the clause "if you saw a photo" there the subjunctive mood or not?

Comment: ***would*** is past tense anyway, so it's perfectly natural to refer to what ***would*** happen if you ***did*** something. That's as opposed to what ***will*** happen if you ***do*** something (or the more explicitly subjunctive *if you **were to** do it*).

Answer (score 4):

The sentence is perfectly idiomatic (at least in American English): it is a conditional in proper form.

A purist might say, given that the speaker intends to show a picture almost immediately,

> This will make more sense once you see a photo

is a better form of conditional, but that is an **opinion** about style.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your point about will+present being "better" than would+past just because the anticipated / hypothetical future is "imminent". Precise contexts may differ, but *on average* it seems to me that an utterance like *It **would** help if you **did** that* is at least *slightly* more likely than *It **will** help if you **do** that*, even when the intended meaning is effectively *Please do that **now***. (Dunno if that makes me "Not a purist"! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I did flag that with “might” and as opinion But if I were **writing** (as opposed to speaking casually), I’d almost certainly write “This explanation will make more sense if you refer to  the diagram on the opposite page” rather than use “would” and “referred.”

Comment: I did start my comment with "**I'm not sure** I agree...". And I do agree that explicit future feels more natural for your "diagram" example. But might that be because ***will*** tends to more strongly imply speaker is "instructing / ordering" audience to do something? ***Will** you be quiet!* sounds stronger / more immediate than ***Would** you be quiet!* to me, for example. It's a shame Google Books doesn't do punctuation marks; I'd have liked to easily compare the percentage of matches for those two with a question mark ("weak"?) and with an exclamation mark ("forceful"?)

Comment: Thank you so much. When he says "if you saw a photo" he is not looking at a photo. He is making a hypothesis of the present. So, is the clause "if you saw a photo" there the subjunctive mood or not?

Comment: I prefer not to talk about the subjunctive in modern English, which has only a few, rapidly disappearing remnants of the subjunctive mode. I prefer using the term “conditionals.” But yes, “if you saw the photo” is a conditional.